# How To Establish A Connection To Database Using C# Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, database-connectivity

Im using Visual Studio 2008 . and wants to connect to database. My Application (in C#) is to develop a form acts like Image Viewer and to perform insert an image and delete an image , Also To Display the images In Database

Comment: I think you should spend some time [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Is that an assignment for all of us? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `DBMS` is `Sql server`. You could do for example

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString here");//conn string here
conn.Open();//if using SqlDataReader
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your query", conn);///your command object
....
.....
```

In order to insert the image to the database, there are mainly two options, either to save the `image path` in the database or save the image itself in database as `BLOB`.

Answer (score 3):

Refer this walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzedkwye%28v=VS.80%29.aspx